# Must access a single item in a jquery array and then simulate a click event (javascript)

Tags: jquery, arrays, events, click, simulate

I want to randomly choose a single `<div>` and then trigger the same event handler that would be triggered if I clicked it. My event handler looks like this:

```
function move(){        
    var currentLeft = $(this).css("left")
    var currentTop = $(this).css("top")
    if($(this).hasClass("movable")){
        $(this)
            .css("left", leftOld)
            .css("top", topOld);
        leftOld = currentLeft;
        topOld = currentTop;
    }
    findMovable();
}
```

Normally this event is triggered by a click event. The event listener looks like this:

```
$(".piece").click(move);
```

I want to have a function that can randomly click these divs and trigger the same event handler. I'm working with something like this, but can't figure out how to finish:

```
$("#shufflebutton").click(shufflePieces);  //event listener

function shufflePieces(){
    var clickTile = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".movable").length);
    $(".movable")[clickTile].trigger(move); //this is the line I can't figure out
}
```

It's important that the event handler (move) knows what div was "clicked" because it must access information regarding that `<div>` using `$(this)`. Any help for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.movable').eq(clickTile).click();
```

`$(...)` returns a jQuery object.  Indexed properties (`[3]`) of a jQuery object return raw DOM elements, not jQuery objects.
To get a jQuery object for a specific element within a jQuery object, call `.eq()`.

Comment: You're a saint. Can't believe I got help in under a minute!